# How do I get Pylance to ignore the possibility of None?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-hinting, python-typing, pylance

I love Pylance type checking.

However, If I have a variable `var: Union[None, T]`, where `T` implements `foo`, pylance will throw an error at:

`var.foo()` since type `None` doesn't implement `foo`.

Is there any way to resolve this? A way to tell Pylance "This variable is `None` sometimes but in this case I'm 100% sure it will be assigned

Comment: does `var: Optional[T]` work?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There are many ways of forcing a type-checker to accept this.

---

1. **Use `assert`**:

   ```
   from typing import Union

   def do_something(var: Union[T, None]):
       assert var is not None
       var.foo()
   ```
2. **Raise some other exception**:

   ```
   from typing import Union

   def do_something(var: Union[T, None]):
       if var is None:
           raise RuntimeError("NO")
       var.foo()
   ```
3. **Use an `if` statement**:

   ```
   from typing import Union

   def do_something(var: Union[T, None]):
       if var is not None:
           var.foo()
   ```
4. **Use `typing.cast`**, a function that does nothing at runtime but forces a type-checker to accept that a variable is of a certain type:

   ```
   from typing import Union, cast

   def do_something(var: Union[T, None]):
       var = cast(T, var)
       var.foo()
   ```
5. **Switch off the type-checker for that line**:

   ```
   from typing import Union

   def do_something(var: Union[T, None]):
       var.foo()  # type: ignore
   ```

---

Note also that, while it makes no difference to how your type annotation is interpreted by a type-checker (the two are semantically identical), you can also write `typing.Union[T, None]` as `typing.Optional[T]`, which is arguably slightly nicer syntax. [In Python >=3.10](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/) (or earlier if you have [`from __future__ import annotations`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) at the top of your code), you can even write `Union` types with the `|` operator, i.e. `T | None`.

Comment: @George I rolled back your edit as `Optional[T]` is semantically identical to `Union[T, None]`. While I agree that it is nicer syntax, it *should* make no difference to how the annotation is interpreted by a type-checker.

Comment: Do you mind letting it in? I get that it's the same but I think the syntax is nicer, it's what I ended up using in my codebase. I guess the question is not so popular anyway, so up to you in the end.

Comment: @George does pylance not complain if you use `var.foo()` after annotating `var` as being of type `Optional[T]`? Mypy sure does, so it's not a solution that's universal for all type-checkers :/ E.g. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=66569c9e53af328165f9259591bedf1f

Comment: I've added a paragraph at the bottom regarding syntax options :)

Comment: @George I've just tested the linked snippet here on Pylance, and it fails on Pylance even with type-checking set to "basic" rather than "strict" (as it should). So I don't see how writing it as `Optional[T]` is a solution to the problem you posed in the question :) https://gist.github.com/AlexWaygood/f9ae35eb43418a2e674826db516dc654

Comment: I was looking for an answer like this. It's neat to see different options on forcing the type checker. Kind of wish this was in the docs for [mypy errors about None/Optional types](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#unexpected-errors-about-none-and-or-optional-types)

Comment: Hmm. I can maybe submit a docs PR to mypy. No promises about when though. (@EhteshChoudhury feel free to submit your own PR to mypy! Some form of credit in the PR description would be nice, if you do want to do so :) I'm @AlexWaygood on github.)

Answer (score 10):

Please don't use blanket `# type: ignore`. Instead be specific on what linting error you want to ignore:

```
myOptionalVar.foo()         # pyright: ignore[reportOptionalMemberAccess]
```

Above works in VSCode default linter Pylance which uses Pyright.

Comment: and if I'm not using pyright?

Answer (score -3):

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71523301/54745

6. **In a class, use a private member and a property**:

   ```
   class something:
       def __init__(self):
           self._var = None

       @property
       def var(self) -> T:
           assert self._var is not None
           return self._var

       def do_something(self)
           self.var.foo()
   ```