# Pylance none-checking with a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylance

I have a class that requires a sequence of actions to be taken:

```py
class SomeModel:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def predict(self, X):
        return None

class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inner_model = None

    def _check_trained(self):
        # Simplified; real version has more checks.
        assert self.inner_model is not None

    def train(self, X, y):
        self.inner_model = SomeModel()
        # More code here

    def predict(self, X):
        self._check_trained()
        return self.inner_model.predict(X)
```

Pylance gives a type error on `self.inner_model.predict` as `self.inner_model` could be `None`. However, this is prevented by the previous check. Unrolling the train check function would fix this but would be unwieldly.

Is there a way to verify the not-None property using a function? Or will I need to explicitly disable the type check for this line?

Additional context:
VSCode 1.65.2
Pylance v2022.3.2
Pylance on basic Type Checking Mode.

Edit: [Here's a screenshot of the behaviour I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF5C3.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @brokenbenchmark says, type checking doesn't extend across function boundaries, so treats `self.inner_model` as an `Optional[Model]`.

One way around this is to return the inner model from `self._check_trained()` and typehint its return type.

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inner_model = None

    def _check_trained(self) -> SomeModel:
        # Simplified; real version has more checks.
        assert self.inner_model is not None
        return self.inner_model

    def train(self, X, y):
        self.inner_model = SomeModel()
        # More code here

    def predict(self, X):
        inner_model = self._check_trained()
        return inner_model.predict(X)
```

Other possible alternatives:

- enforce assignment of the inner model in `__init__` so it can't be `None`
- Store `inner_model` as a private variable and expose it via a property that does the check and returns a `SomeModel`:

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self._inner_model = None

    @property
    def inner_model(self) -> SomeModel:
        assert self._inner_model is not None
        return self._inner_model
        

    def _check_trained(self):
        # Simplified; real version has more checks.
        assert self.inner_model is not None

    def train(self, X, y):
        self._inner_model = SomeModel()
        # More code here

    def predict(self, X):
        self._check_trained()
        return self.inner_model.predict(X)
```

Comment: Your second suggestion here is great - I'll probably take that approach!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like Pylance treats the assertion as a postcondition of the function. I couldn't find a specific source for this, but I have seen behaviors like this from other static analysis tools -- automatically generating such postconditions could make the analysis quickly intractable.

You can either use `# type: ignore` on the line where the call to `.predict()` is made, but if you're accessing the same variable many times over, it would be better to use `cast()`, like so:

```py
from typing import cast

def predict(self, X):
    self._check_trained()
    inner_model = cast(SomeModel, self.inner_model)
    return inner_model.predict(X)
```

Some further discussion on handling nullable values with Pylance can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68468805/17769815).