# How to solve "capitalize is not a known number of None" Pylance

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance

## VSCODE PYLANCE ISSUE

While converting a string with capitalize() in python system is giving error: "capitalize is not a known member of None" Pylance(ReportOptionalMemberAccess). This error is coming for lower(), casefold() or upper()

Please suggest how to get rid of this.

[image]

I need to pass both the lower and upper case string as query.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68446642/how-do-i-get-pylance-to-ignore-the-possibility-of-none

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get Pylance to ignore the possibility of None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68446642/how-do-i-get-pylance-to-ignore-the-possibility-of-none)