# manipulate Pymysql SELECT statement

Tags: python, dictionary, pymysql

I'm trying to run a pymysql select statement, and use the datetime in my code. I was able to print the output and the query is correct, but I can't run dict commands on the variable I used to store the data. It keeps saying the type of the object is None, even though I declared it as an empty dict at the start of my function.

The output return as follows: `{'last_date': datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 9, 13, 30)}`. How do I manipulate these numbers so I can build a datetime objetct in my script?

EDIT: my query is: "`SELECT last_date from mysqldb.table_name ORDER BY last_date DESC LIMIT 1`"

last_date type in the database is datetime(3)

EDIT2: Here is the code:

```
last_date = {}
sqlQuery = "(...)"
cursorObject.execute(sqlQuery)
last_date = cursorObject.fetchone()
```

I'm having trouble to access the data inside last_date, when using dict functions it returns like: `(...) is not a known member of "None"`

Comment: You haven't shown your query. That's pretty important.

Comment: Please post your Python code. The dictionary you show is clearly not `None`, so we need to see where you're getting that. And include the full traceback.

Comment: `last_date` will be `None` if the query doesn't return anything. But since the query has no `WHERE` condition, that would only happen if the table is empty.

Comment: That error message doesn't come from Python, it comes from Pylance. Your code should be using `last_date['last_date']` to access the dictionary element.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68446642/how-do-i-get-pylance-to-ignore-the-possibility-of-none for how to fix the Pylance warning.